# React rendering the component twice and 2nd disappears after a flash, [DOM] found 2 elements with non-unique id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a Login page and when I redirect from Register Page to Login Page, I am seeing login page twice and in the console I am getting a warning 
[DOM] Found 2 elements with non_unique id "username_login".

I am using React along with django. I have tried changing if-else, lifecycle methods, but nothing fruitful. Please help!!

1. Login Page

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react'
   import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
   import { connect } from 'react-redux';
   import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
   import { login } from '../../actions/auth';
   import Loader from "../common/Loader";
   export class Login extends Component {
       constructor() {
           super();
           this.state = {
               username: '',
               password: '',
           };
       }

       static propTypes = {
           login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
           isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
           user: PropTypes.object,
           isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
       };

       onChange = e => {
           const key = e.target.name;
           const val = e.target.value;
           this.setState(() => ({ [key]: val }));
           if (key === 'username') {
               this.setState(() => ({ username: val.toUpperCase() }));
           }

       };

       onSubmit = e => {
           e.preventDefault();
           const { username, password } = this.state;
           this.props.login(username.toLowerCase(), password);
       };

       componentWillMount() {
           const { isLoading } = this.props;
           if (isLoading)
               return <Loader />
       }

       render() {
           const { isAuthenticated, user, isLoading } = this.props;
           if (isAuthenticated) {
               if (user !== null && !user.participant.firstTimer) {

                   return <Redirect to="/" />
               }
               else {
                   return <Redirect to="/update" />
               }
           }
           const { username, password } = this.state;
           return (
               <div>
                   {isLoading ? <Loader /> : (
                       <div className="col-md-6 m-auto upper-padding">
                           <div className="mt-5 main">
                               <h2 className="text-center">Login</h2>
                               <br />
                               <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                                   <div className="form-group">
                                       <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                                       <div className="input-outer">
                                           <input
                                               type="text"
                                               className="form-control input"
                                               name="username"
                                               onChange={this.onChange}
                                               value={username}
                                               tabIndex="1"
                                               id="username_login"
                                               spellCheck="false"
                                               autoComplete="off"
                                           />
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                                   <div className="form-group">
                                       <label>Password</label>
                                       <div className="input-outer">
                                           <input
                                               type="password"
                                               className="form-control input"
                                               name="password"
                                               onChange={this.onChange}
                                               value={password}
                                               tabIndex="2"
                                               autoComplete={"password"}
                                               spellCheck="false"
                                           />
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                                   <br />
                                   <div className="form-group">
                                       <button type="submit" className="btn btn-slide" tabIndex="3">
                                           Login
                               </button>
                                   </div>
                                   <p>
                                       Don't have an account? <Link tabIndex="4" to="/register">Register</Link>
                                   </p>
                               </form>
                           </div>
                       </div>)
                   }
               </div>
           )
       }
   }

   const mapStateToProps = state => ({
       isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
       user: state.auth.user,
       isLoading: state.auth.isLoading
   });

   export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login })(Login);
   ```
2. Register Page

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react'
   import { NavLink, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
   import { connect } from 'react-redux';
   import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
   import { register } from '../../actions/auth';
   import { createMessage } from '../../actions/messages';
   import Loader from "../common/Loader";
   export class Register extends Component {
       state = {
           username: '',
           email: '',
           password: '',
           password2: ''
       };

       static propTypes = {
           register: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
           isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
           createMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
           user: PropTypes.object,
           isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
       };

       onChange = e => {
           const key = e.target.name;
           const val = e.target.value;
           this.setState(() => ({ [key]: val }));
           if (key === 'username') {
               this.setState(() => ({ username: val.toUpperCase() }));
           }
       };

       onSubmit = (e) => {
           e.preventDefault();
           const { username, email, password, password2 } = this.state;
           if (password !== password2) {
               this.props.createMessage({ passwordsNotMatch: 'Passwords do not match.' })
           }
           else {
               const user = { username: username.toLowerCase(), email, password };
               this.props.register(user);
           }

       };

       render() {
           const { isAuthenticated, user, isLoading } = this.props;
           if (isAuthenticated) {
               if (user !== null && !user.participant.firstTimer) {
                   return <Redirect to="/" />
               }
               else {
                   return <Redirect to="/update" />
               }
           }
           if (isLoading) {
               return (<Loader />)
           }
           const { username, email, password, password2 } = this.state;
           return (
               <div className="col-md-6 m-auto upper-padding-register">
                   <div className="mt-5 main">
                       <h2 className="text-center">Register</h2>
                       <br />
                       <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                           <div className="form-group">
                               <label>Username</label>
                               <div className="input-outer">
                                   <input
                                       type="text"
                                       className="form-control input"
                                       name="username"
                                       onChange={this.onChange}
                                       value={username}
                                       tabIndex="1"
                                       spellCheck="false"
                                   />
                               </div>
                           </div>
                           <div className="form-group">
                               <label>Email</label>
                               <div className="input-outer">
                                   <input
                                       type="email"
                                       className="form-control input"
                                       name="email"
                                       onChange={this.onChange}
                                       value={email}
                                       tabIndex="2"
                                       spellCheck="false"
                                   />
                               </div>
                           </div>
                           <div className="form-group">
                               <label>Password</label>
                               <div className="input-outer">
                                   <input
                                       type="password"
                                       className="form-control input"
                                       name="password"
                                       onChange={this.onChange}
                                       value={password}
                                       tabIndex="3"
                                       spellCheck="false"
                                   />
                               </div>
                           </div>
                           <div className="form-group">
                               <label>Confirm Password</label>
                               <div className="input-outer">
                                   <input
                                       type="password"
                                       className="form-control input"
                                       name="password2"
                                       onChange={this.onChange}
                                       value={password2}
                                       tabIndex="4"
                                       spellCheck="false"
                                   />
                               </div>
                           </div>
                           <div className="form-group">
                               <button type="submit" className="btn btn-slide" tabIndex="5">
                                   Register
                               </button>
                           </div>
                           <p>
                               Already have an account? <NavLink tabIndex="5" to="/login">Login</NavLink>
                           </p>
                       </form>
                   </div>
               </div>
           )
       }
   }

   const mapStateToProps = state => ({
       isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
       user: state.auth.user,
       isLoading: state.auth.isLoading
   });

   export default connect(mapStateToProps, { register, createMessage })(Register);
   ```

Register Action:

```
export const register = ({username, email, password}) => dispatch => {
  const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };
  const body = JSON.stringify({username, email, password});
  axios.post(`${'URL'}/api/auth/register, body, config`)
    .then(res => { dispatch({ type: REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: res.data }); })
    .catch(err => { dispatch({ type: REGISTER_FAIL }); })
};
```

Comment: Can you include `register` action?

Comment: But I am getting the error when I click on Login Link in the Register.js file

Comment: `export const register = ({username, email, password}) => dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    const body = JSON.stringify({username, email, password});
    axios.post(`${URL}/api/auth/register`, body, config)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data
            });
        }).catch(err => {
        dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_FAIL
        });
    })
};`

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider this:

1. at your *Register* component:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; //or react-router, depends on what you prefer
/**
// ----------
// the rest of your code
// ----------
**/
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, { register, createMessage })(Register));
```

2. then, pass *history* which was provided to your component by using `withRouter` HOC to the `register` action.

```
    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { username, email, password, password2 } = this.state;
        if (password !== password2) {
            this.props.createMessage({ passwordsNotMatch: 'Passwords do not match.' })
        }
        else {
            const user = { username: username.toLowerCase(), email, password };
            this.props.register(user, this.props.history);
        }

    };
```

3. inside your `register` action, use history to redirect the user on success.

```
export const register = ({username, email, password}, history) => dispatch => {
  const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };
  const body = JSON.stringify({username, email, password});
  axios.post(`${'URL'}/api/auth/register, body, config`)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({ type: REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: res.data });
      history.push('/login'); //use the pathname for login page!
    })
    .catch(err => { dispatch({ type: REGISTER_FAIL }); })
};
```

This is only a possible fix, going around your logic which waits for `props` changes to happen then redirect depending on conditional blocks you have at the top of the `render` method of your `register` component.

The problem also, a possibility, might be at the component which is returned for route `/update`, if the previous alternations didn't work as expected, please provide a snap for the `/update` component -as an edit to the original question-

Comment: Hi, The issue is not when I am registering. It is when I am trying to go from one page to another.
check this video here. This may make the issue more clear.
[Issue Video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1arIrh-eZX3BJkDsUTVl2CLqjOmOpxOch)

Comment: Also, can you tell me whether to use react-router-redux for redirecting??

Comment: Sorry for that, it's weird enough that going to `/login` redirects to `/register` since there is no logic at the `Login` component that redirect to the `/register` route. It's ok to just keep the `Redirect` from `react-router-dom`, I guess the problem is in a Higher Level component, is it correct that you have certain logic in a higher level that might redirect to `/register` page?

Comment: Solved!!
The problem was with animation. There was a timeout b/w the 2 routes due to which the component was stored due to its lifecycle. I just removed the timeout, this solved the double problem, but now I am unable to use any transition upon transitioning b/w different routes.

Comment: Great! good job, you must have learnt something through that. Basically, for transitions to be made animated, you'll need to have something that intercepts the routing changes, there are some packages that made it easier [such like react-nprogress](https://github.com/tanem/react-nprogress),